# How can I validate the data type of the spark DataFrame column programmatically ?

Tags: unit-testing, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I have created a Unit Test in IntelliJ for a function which is doing the type casting. So in my unit test, I want to validate using `assert` statement as following :

```
assert(testDF.select(col1).dataType == Integer)
```

So if the above assert statement satisfies the unit test will be success.

Can anyone please help on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can for example use pattern matching:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType

assert(testDF.schema(col1).dataType match {
  case IntegerType => true
  case _ => false
})
```

If you want to match another properties

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField

assert(testDF.schema(col1) match {
  case StructField(_, IntegerType, nullable, _) => true
  case _ => false
})
```